# Facebook cookie and oauth 2.0 changes

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, oauth-2.0

This function used to work for me until the other day when facebook decided to enforce some changes.

```
    function get_facebook_cookie() {
    $app_id             = '[MyAppID]';
    $application_secret = '[MyAppSecrect]';

    if(isset($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id])){
        $args = array();
        parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);
        ksort($args);
        $payload = '';
        foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
                if ($key != 'sig') {
                $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
                }
        }
        if (md5($payload . $application_secret) != $args['sig']) {
                return null;
        }
        return $args;
        } else {
         return null;
        }
}
```

I was the able to get the FB users access token as easily as

```
$cookie['access_token']
```

Now it doesn't seem that I'm able to retrieve this info anymore.

I was successfully (easily) able to make the required changes to my javascript code, but I'm kind of stumped on the php side.  As a quick side note I'm using codeigniter and I've had a lot of trouble trying to get the FB PHP SDK to play nice, also I havne't seen any examples of integrating the PHP 3 SDK into codeigniter so I'm looking for a quick and dirty solution that will allow me to get the access token from the cookie thus allowing me to use the following call to Facebooks API:

```
'https://api.facebook.com/method/friends.getAppUsers?access_token=' . $cookie['access_token'];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's because facebook change cookie name from `fbs_` to `fbsr_`.

But there was more changes. Just follow [this steps](http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/entry/oauth-20-facebook-changes-and-cookie-problem-in-codeigniter/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Changing the code to fbsr_ throws back the following php error "Message: Undefined index: sig" which is referring to this line in my code above "if (md5($payload . $application_secret) != $args['sig'])". Any ideas?

Comment: The best bet is to var_dump your $args to see what you actually have.

Comment: there was more changes, check if this suggestions work: [link](http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/entry/oauth-20-facebook-changes-and-cookie-problem-in-codeigniter/)

Comment: Kokers - that link worked like a charm! I had seen that new Oauth 2.0 authorization code before (on FB's site - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and I had tried to convert in a similar manner, but couldn't get it to work.  The link you provided saved me tons of time. If you want to re-post as an answer I will accept it.