# Facebook Connect SDK not working after the 13th december

Tags: sdk, facebook

I'm struggling with my Facebook Connect after December the 13th.

Here my Facebook.php based on the old PHP SDK 2.0 - hoping someone can point me in the right direction in order to make it functional again.

http://pastebin.com/Mvu1JeZY

I've read that `$session` is now `$user` - and `params` in the JavaScript is now `scope`.
What else would need to be changed?

Specifically, is this still valid?

http://pastebin.com/8VAv0te5

My JavaScript is getting the login and user correctly. Its my PHP which needs an update.

Answer (score 0):

there was many changes between SDK 2.0 and 3.x.

As I see in your code, you use old cookie function which will not work. There was similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537007/facebook-cookie-and-oauth-2-0-changes/)

Some changes and quick fix for them you can find [here](http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/entry/oauth-20-facebook-changes-and-cookie-problem-in-codeigniter/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the new oauth sdk : http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/614/