# Using accessToken with Facebook cookie

Tags: facebook, cookies

Since last week's update in the Facebook API, my login doesn't work anymore: even if I do my login, the login button remains there and does not disappear. But the button does nothing when clicking it. While I am already logged in, there's no 2nd login needed and so the Login button shouldn't be visible. Before it disappeared and a message like "Welcome 'First Name Last Name'" appeared there.

I located the problem: it's this part getting the information of the Facebook cookie here:

```
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?accessToken=' .
                                      $cookie['accessToken']));
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There was similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537007/facebook-cookie-and-oauth-2-0-changes/) it's all about new SDK and changes between new and old version.